# Commands for enabling remote desktop in ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ubuntu

Please can you give me the required steps to enable remote desktop in ubuntu 9.04 through command lines.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does not have remote desktop as windows, but it has vnc. But I recommend to use [x2go](http://www.x2go.org/index.php?id=6) instead of vnc, x2go is much faster than vnc especially if you are on a slow connection.

Comment: [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/), although somewhat dated, also deserves a look as it works quite well over WAN connections, is included with Ubuntu 9.04 and has [walkthroughs for this system](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/3207-installing-freenx-under-ubuntu-9-04).